# default text in android layout

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

in instagram app, when image is not available it says

> "tap to retry"

and when image is available it loads image.

my app needs something like that, if information is available it loads information onto the linear layout, if not available it returns nothing so my layout remains blank.

so how do i add the text like instagram like " no information available".

I tried using

> android:hint

but it doesnt seem to be a good option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how you have anything set up, but I would think something like this would work. Have your ImageView and TextView fill the same space, then toggle which one is visible and which one isn't based on the presence of the image. Hope this helps

Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
 ... >


   <ImageView
   ...
   />

   <TextView
   ...
   />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Logic:

```
if(isImageAvail){
   iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   tv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}else{
   iv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you'd have your drawable...

```
Drawable imageDrawable = codeToGetYourImage;
TextView errorTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.your_text_id);
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.your_image_id);

if(imageDrawable == null){
    imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(imageDrawable);
} else {
    imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    errorTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/your_text_id"/>

<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sorry, image cannot be displayed"
        android:id="@+id/your_image_id"/>

</LinearLayout>
```